# Powershell - move files from subfolders to parent directory

Tags: powershell, copy

I have a folder with a lot of folders in it. I want to be able to look in the folder that has been modified today - and only copy the files with a .txt extension. I want to move them up a level. So in the picture below, I only want to search the folder that was modified today (yesterdays date in the picture), no need to check the names of the folders.

If I have a structure like this
I want the files in the folders appear directly below in the folder.
I also want to check that if there file in the folder that it is not already present in the root folder
[image]

I have the following code that does move the files, but without the logic for checking the folder with todays modified on and the check if the file is already present.

```
Get-Childitem -Filter '*.txt' -Path "H:\FOLDERS\" -Recurse | Where lastwritetime -ge $(Get-Date).Date | Copy-Item -Destination "H:\FOLDERS\"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below code -

```
$RootFolder = "H:\Folders"          #Defining the root directory
$Yesterday = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1) #Last modified date of the folder should be yesterday
$RecentFolders = Get-Childitem $RootFolder | Where-Object {$_.lastwritetime -gt $Yesterday.date}

foreach($file in $RecentFolders.FullName)
{
    $Destination = Split-Path $file         #Selecting one folder up
    $TxtFile = Get-Childitem -path $file -filter '*.txt'    #Text files selected
    Copy-Item $TxtFile.FullName -Destination $Destination   #Copy operation

}
```

If you want to select only those folders which are modified today, you can change the variables as

```
$Today = Get-Date
$RecentFolders = Get-Childitem $RootFolder | Where-Object {$_.lastwritetime -gt $Today.date}
```

Comment: Hi
Works great :)
If I want to check the root-folder before the Copy-item executes - that the file is already there, is that possible?

Comment: Yes that can be done. You can look at [Test-Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-path?view=powershell-7.3#examples)  before the copy and then perform the copy based on the result of the Test-Path.

Comment: If this answer works for you @HenrikRosqvist, please select the check mark on it.